# Extract rows from multiple fields of a structure

Tags: matlab, indexing, struct, reference, cell-array

A structure  (25 fields) of column vectors (100 rows) is created. How to extract its particular rows. For example,

```
s.a=[1 2 3 4 5 6]'
s.b=[5 2 8 1 0 4]'
s.c=[9 7 0 1 3 5]'
% 2 to 4 rows to be extracted
% expected output
t.a=[2 3 4]'
t.b=[2 8 1]'
t.c=[7 0 1]'
```

indexing on struct is not working.
what could be the generic way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use `structfun`

```
t = structfun(@(x)x(2:4),s,'UniformOutput',false)
```

Comment: On my machine with 2017b structfun is actually slower than a standard loop.

Comment: `structfun`, `arrayfun` and all this kind of function simply hide a for loop, so it's not necesseraly faster but it's easier to read. And you can combine several fun function together, for example if you have an array of struct you can write: `arrayfun(@(y)structfun(@(x)x(2:4),y,'UniformOutput',false),s)` instead of 2 nested for loop.

Comment: I know, that's why I said *standard*. Sure, it's more readable but it's slower. The difference was about a factor of two. Quite significant right?

Comment: You can't just said "it's slower" without having benchmarked the two solution with structure of different size. Probably the `structfun` solution will be slower for small amount of data but a little bit more efficient for big amount of data. Try again with a structure that contains 10000 or 100000 fields.

Comment: @obchardon: How to select values in a row of a structure (a structure with some fields) using a function like `structfun` in Matlab? Ex:  `row num = 98` , with  values: `[121    0.458    21908]`, that `[121    0.458    21908]` should be selected using its row number.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `struct2array` to convert the struct to an array, extract rows, then convert back.

```
s.a=[1 2 3 4 5 6]';
s.b=[5 2 8 1 0 4]';
s.c=[9 7 0 1 3 5]';
lowest_row=2;
highest_row=4;
num_of_fields=length(fieldnames(s)); % Will be 25 in your code

mat = struct2array(s); % Convert struct to matrix
extracted_mat = mat(lowest_row:highest_row,:); % Extract wanted rows from mat

abc_vec=char(97:122);

% Convert back to struct
for i=1:num_of_fields
    t.(abc_vec(i))=extracted_mat(:,i);
end
```

Comment: Actual data contains 25 fields and 100 rows. So does it mean 5+25 line of code. Isn't there any elegant way to handle.

Comment: @M.Patil why 5+25? This code will work for any number of fields

Comment: @M.Patil The first three rows are the initialization of your initial struct, so these are not part of the code. The rest of the code will be them same length for any struct size (any number of fields and rows)

Answer (score 1):

Just select the particular rows in the struct.

```
% getting the fieldnames of the struct
field = fieldnames(s)

% length of the struct

len = length(field)

startRow = 2;
endRow = 4;

for ii = 1:1:len
   t.(field{ii,1}) = s.(field{ii,1})(startRow:endRow)
end
```